# XML to html using xslt dynamically

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I have an xml file stored in database . I want to retrieve and display it on the browser using and xlt . How do i do it  in asp.net

SqlConnection(strConnection);
 byte[] file = null; SqlDataAdapter da;

da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Data From Table where id ='" + 3 + "' ", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet(); da.Fill(ds); file = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Data"];

string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath());

Xml1.DocumentContent = xmlString;

Xml1.TransformSource = Server.MapPath("~/abc.xsl");

Comment: Read up about the ExecuteXmlReader method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and the XSLTCompiledTransform class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I need Sample code plz . i am using byte to hold my xml file .

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really about providing code samples, but solving specific coding problems. If you have a look on MSDN you should be able to find some code examples yourself (possibly using the "GetBytes" method of the SQLDataReader). If you can't get it to work, post the code you have tried so far, and the problems you are encountering. Thanks.

Comment: Hii This is my Code
I need to pass my retrieved file in the Server.Map Path

con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        byte[] file = null;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Data From Table where id ='" + 3 + "' ", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        file = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Data"];
        string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath());
        Xml1.DocumentContent = xmlString;
        Xml1.TransformSource = Server.MapPath("~/abc.xsl");

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your current code. It is very hard to read in comments. Thank you.

Comment: done . you can see it now